# Date field update with now() when assign Carbon date object

Tags: php, laravel, date, model

My problem is about date property update with the laravel Eloquant model system.

Sometimes when I change the instruction property (and sometimes even the date), the instruction property is updated with success, but the date property is set to now, which is not normal.

But when I use my update function (see it below) to update the date only, my problem doesn't occur.
That problem doesn't appear every time and I don't understand why.

My php app runs on an Apache 2 server, with php 7.3, Laravel 5.8 and MariaDB 10.3.15.

I've tried to save my model after instruction update and after date update but I doesn't change anythings.
Also, a dump of the $delivery var after saving shows the correct date, but the date registered in the database is the same date than the "updated_at" property.

My update function in the controller:

```
public function update(UpdateDeliveryRequest $request)
    {
        $delivery = Delivery::find($request->input('id'));

        if (!(is_null($request->input('instructions'))))
            $delivery->instructions = $request->input('instructions');

        $date = Carbon::create($request->input('date'));
        $date->shiftTimezone(Config::get('app.timezone'));
        $date->setTimezone('UTC'); // Set time to UTC for storing

        $delivery->date = $date;
        $delivery->save();
    }
```

My Delivery model:

```
class Delivery extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'deliveryForm_id', 'user_id', 'date', 'instructions',
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'date',
    ];
}
```

Date attribute must to be choosen by the user.
Instructions attibute is a string which is written by the user too.

I want to my date property equal with the input date in any case.

Thank's for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `Carbon::create($request->input('date'))` returns the date you expect? I suspect the input date cannot be parsed and therefore now is used instead. If you add `$date = Carbon::yesterday();` before saving, does that change the date stored in the database?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, a dump gives the right date. Adding Carbon::yesterday to date doesn't change anything